# Unity3D define static js var available from c#

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to define a static var in UnityScript.

The problem is that my script does not reside within a class.

How can i create a global variable that can be accessed from a C# class and
a UnityScript script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is place the scripts in the correct folders in your Project tab. The script you want to have access must be inside the **Standard Assets** or the **Plugins** folder. The other script has to be placed outside these folders. After this step, just call the **GetComponent()** method as any other Component. Here’s a JavaScript example:

```
//create a variable to access the C# script  
private var csScript : CSharp1;  
function Awake()  
{  
    //Get the CSharp Script  
    csScript = this.GetComponent("CSharp1"); //Don't forget to place the 'CSharp1'
file inside the 'Standard Assets' folder  
}  
//... code here
```

Now, here’s a C# example:

```
using UnityEngine;  
using System.Collections;  
public class CSharp2 : MonoBehaviour   
{  
    //create a variable to access the JavaScript script  
    private JS1 jsScript;   

    void Awake()  
    {  
        //Get the JavaScript component  
        jsScript = this.GetComponent<JS1>(); //Don't forget to place the 'JS1' file inside the 'Standard Assets' folder  
    }  
//...  
}
```

And this is how it’s done. There’s no way to have access to C# and JavaScript simultaneously, as one of the scripts must be at **Standard Assets** or **Plugins** folder. Scripts placed inside one of these folders are compiled first, meaning these scripts can’t access the ones outside it, as they are not compiled yet (more information [here](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html)).

There is a Project With Example [here](http://www.41post.com/uploads/files/JS-CSharp_CSharp-JS.zip)

Comment: thanks. this also helped me http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html